# How do I debug a static library in Atmel Studio 7?

Tags: debugging, arm, static-libraries, atmelstudio

I have two Atmel Studio projects: projA which produces a library file (.a) and projB which produces an executable file (.elf). projA is used within projB as a static library. I can compile projB with references to projA and upload the .elf to my microcontroller with no issue. I know the code from projA is executing on the microcontroller. When I try to debug the code, single-stepping through lines of code will completely skip any functions declared and defined in projA that are referenced to in projB.

Initially, I only linked the .a file from projA to projB's toolchain. projB's solution had no reference to the source code for projA. The debugger never stepped through projA's source code, which makes sense. I have since linked both projA and projB to the same solution within Atmel Studio 7. Now the solution knows how to find the source code for references to functions declared & defined in projA that are referenced to in projB. However, debugging still fails to single-step through code written in projA. I even double checked to make sure both projA and projB are compiled in Debug mode and not Release mode.

Is there something I'm forgetting that prevents me from single-stepping through projA's source code while debugging in AS7? I want to be able to step through projA's code line by line.